# Debugging Office Addins (VSTO) with different office versions 2010/2013/2016

Tags: vsto, office-interop, office-addins

Happy New Year everyone!

I'm building an Outlook Add-in (non-web), and it works really good at home (Office 365/2016).  At work, I have office 2013, and some features don't work very well on it.  So, since I have VS2017 on both computers, and my code is on Azure, I can go ahead, and download it, run it, and it should work, however I get the error that I can't debug it because of the version difference.

So, After digging around the net, the most popular answer was tell the add-in to run by giving the path to this version of outlook.  The problem with this, is that I'm not able to hit break points, etc.

Now that you have some background, here is the problem I have and the question I need answered.  Is there a definitive guide or best practice to allow me to 'debug' as well as test my add-in across different office platforms, or, is there a way to adjust the code/package to allow me to debug on any office platform out there?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The rule of thumb is to develop against the oldest version the add-in should work with. That ensures that it won't try to use features not available in older versions. Since, generally, Microsoft is pretty good about backwards compatibility that should make needing to intensively debug less of an issue. Beyond that, since you provide no information about what kinds of problems you're encountering, it's difficult to know what to tell you.

Comment: @CindyMeister, The problem I'm having is that I am unable to debug the package because it says I have the incorrect version of office running.  Now I built it with the Office 2010 interop package, so it should be compatible, however, it doesn't debug with office 2010, or 2013, only 2016.  I need to know how to get it to test.

Comment: In order to debug with Office 2010, that version must be installed - and that should be the only version of Office installed on the development machine. From you problem description it doesn't sound like that's the case?

Comment: Let me break it down a little more.  When you build a VSTO and you try to debug it on a machine that doesn't have the same version of Office on it, it will not work.  You get Visual Studio debug errors, saying you can't debug on this system.  Any bypasses you use, results in the inability to run breakpoints.  
If you're not familiar with this, I find it really hard to explain it beyond that.  "You cannot debug or run this project, because the required version of the Microsoft Office application is not installed"

Comment: You can familiarize yourself with the error by searching that, but you won't find anything but work arounds.  I need to know how to be able to develop, test, and debug on different versions of office.